# Sparql query with both Union and Filter Criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, sparql, rdflib

How to use both union statement and regex pattern filter in a Sparql query when using Python, RDFLib.

I need to obtain resources from a graph which are involved in either p1 or p2 property, and include "example.net/" as prefix. I have tried a number of variations, but all return errors. for example:

```
    myd = Namespace("http://example.net/")
    nmg.bind("myd", myd)
    
    records = g.query('''select distinct ?s ?o where 
    { 
    {{?s myd.p1 ?o} Union {?s myd.p2 ?o}}
    filter(regex(str(?s),"http://example.net/"))
    }''')
```

Suppose I have the following triples:

```
    a p1 b  (prefix is example.net/)
    e p1 d  (prefix is example.net/)
    x p2 z  (prefix is example.net/)
    i p2 t  (prefix is anotherExample.net/)
```

I want my query to return (a p1 b), (e p1 d), and (x p2 z) which satisfy all the conditions. I am using Jupyter Notebooks, RDFLib.

Comment: what kind of "error" do you get? I mean, you SPARQL query prefix usage is wrong: it has to be `myd:p1` and `myd:p2` - a prefix is used via a colon, not a dot as separator: `prefix:rest`

Comment: also, why aren't you using `strstarts` filter function instead of regex? `filter(strstarts(str(?s),"http://example.net/"))`

Comment: @UninformedUser Appreciate the feedback, you were correct about the syntax error. Would you like to add an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: glad it helped, beginning with SPARQL and URIs can be tricky ... Feel free to add and answer your own question - it's a trivial syntax fix. Cheers